# React calls API every time user updates state and keeps old api alive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

i have issue when page loads it calls api one time, after user changes date it calls api again to change data to that date but it keeps old api alive and adding new one also, with this page gets very slow,

***this is api when page loads***

[image: this is api when page loads]

***this is api when date updated two time***

[image]

***this is code when i call api on page load***

```html
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData(this.state.startDate, this.state.endDate);

  }
```

***this is code every time i update api***

```html
 updateDate = (start, end) => {
      this.setState({startDate: start})
      this.setState({endDate: end})
      this.fetchData(this.state.startDate.startDate, this.state.endDate.endDate);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

### **What you are seeing at the network tab is a list of `history` fetch that you called**

This means that they are not all alive but rather history records, it's only `alive` in your term if they are having status pending.

You would need to check for a performance issue somewhere else, such as server response time or re-rendering of components.

---

**Here is a pending status:**

[image: A pending status]

Comment: first of all thank you for respond, none of them have pending but every time i update api data it getting more and more slow and i thought that problem was there

Comment: Obviously, it's not. You would need to trace your request further more. Like.. what happens before/after your request is triggered.

Comment: Gladly so, mate

Answer (score -1):

Correct way is to use `this.setState({object}`, callBack after state is changed)

```
this.setState({startDate: start, endDate: end}, this.fetchDate(startDate,endDate))
```

You need to club these two lines to one .

```
this.setState({startDate: start})
this.setState({endDate: end})
```

to

```
this.setState({startDate: start, endDate: end})
```